# ReactJs + Reflux // trigger is executed on null component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I'm trying to use Reflux inside my ReactJs app.

I'm having an issue where a component listening to a data store is executing the callback on an empty component instance instead of the actual component that was instanced.

Upon calling the action ***toggleUserBar***, the datastore is called and performs the trigger. In the component ***Sidebar***, the callback is called but the component state is empty:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sd' of undefined

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**actions.tsx**

```
var Reflux = require('reflux');
var RQ = {};

RQ.actions = Reflux.createActions([
    "toggleUserBar"
]);

window.RQ = RQ;
```

**store.tsx**

```
RQ.store = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [RQ.actions],
  init: function() {},
  onToggleUserBar: function() {
      this.trigger();
  }
});
```

**sidebar.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM  from "react-dom";

const LeftNav = require('material-ui/lib/left-nav');
const Menu = require('material-ui/lib/menu/menu')

interface ISidebarProps extends React.Props<any> {

}

interface ISidebarState extends React.Props<any> {
    shown: Boolean;
    sd: any;
}

export class Sidebar extends React.Component<ISidebarProps, ISidebarState> {

  unsubscribe: any;

  constructor(props: ISidebarProps) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { shown: true, sd: null };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = RQ.store.listen(function() {
      this.state.sd.setState({ open: true });
    });
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unsubscribe();
  };

  render() {

    let menuItems = [
      { route: 'get-started', text: 'Get Started' },
      { route: 'customization', text: 'Customization' },
      { route: 'components', text: 'Components' }
    ];

    return (
      <LeftNav ref={(c) => this.state.sd = c} docked={false} openRight={true} menuItems={menuItems} />
    );

  };

}
```

The sidebar component is rendered in another component:

```
<ComSidebar ref={(c) => sdref = c} />
```

If I manually call ***sdref.state.sd.open = true***, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword in JavaScript often behaves in surprising ways. You've found the major one.

When you create an inner function using the `function` keyword, it doesn't get the same `this` variable as the enclosing function. So that means, in your code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // "this" out here is your component instance
  this.unsubscribe = RQ.store.listen(function() {
    // "this" in here is NOT the same - undefined, as you're seeing
    this.setState({ open: true });
  });
};
```

There are several ways to fix this. Since you're using ES6, the easiest is probably to use an arrow function - arrow functions explicitly keep the `this` reference of their enclosing function. It would look like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = RQ.store.listen(() => {
    // now it's the same "this"
    this.setState({ open: true });
  });
};
```

If you weren't using ES6, you could get this same behavior by calling `bind` on that function (which allows you to specify the `this` variable, as well as any parameters to it):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = RQ.store.listen(function() {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  }.bind(this)); 
  // by calling bind, we are explicitly setting the "this" variable here
  // passing it from outer scope to inner scope
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this.state.sd.setState({ open: true }); should be this.setState({open: true}).

```js
export class Sidebar extends React.Component<ISidebarProps, ISidebarState> {

  unsubscribe: any;

  constructor(props: ISidebarProps) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { shown: true, sd: null };
      this.storeDidChange = this.storeDidChange.bind(this);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = RQ.store.listen(this.storeDidChange);
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unsubscribe();
  };

  storeDidChange() {
    this.refs.leftnav.open = true;
  }

  render() {

    let menuItems = [
      { route: 'get-started', text: 'Get Started' },
      { route: 'customization', text: 'Customization' },
      { route: 'components', text: 'Components' }
    ];

    return (
      <LeftNav ref={leftnav} docked={false} openRight={true} menuItems={menuItems} />
    );

  };

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "this.setState is not a function". Looks like "this" is null for some reason...